# Replace regex for visual studio?

Tags: regex, visual-studio, search, visual-studio-2012, replace

What could the regex be to replace all instances of `NBinTree<Whatever_1>::Whatever_2` with `NBinTreeWhatever_2<Whatever_1>`?

I tried `.NBinTree<\1>::\2[ ]$` for the search and `NBinTree\2<\1>` for the replace but it doesn't do anything at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace matches of `NBinTree<(\w+)>::(\w+)` with `NBinTree$2<$1>`.

Make sure that the "Use Regular Expressions" box is checked.